# How to calculate variance of $Var(\hat{\beta_0}+\hat{\beta_1}x^*)$ in linear regression(predicting value of y)?

Tags: statistics, variance, parameter-estimation, linear-regression

Why is $Var(\hat{\beta_0}+\hat{\beta_1}x^*)=\frac{1}{n}+(\frac{(x-x^*)^2}{S_{xx}})\sigma^{2}$ ?

Although I tried to separate them to $Var(\hat{\beta_0})+Var(\hat{\beta_1}x^*)+2Cov(\hat{\beta_0},\hat{\beta_1x^*})$, but I am not sure how to continue with $Var(\hat{\beta_1}x^*)$.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQXsj.png)

Comment: Please include your attempt and use mathjax to type your post.

Comment: I am thinking of separate the Var(X+Y) terms but I am not sure how to do with Var(beta1 x*)?

Comment: Hi, try to include your attempt by directly editing your post.

Comment: Actually this is my first question, I am not sure what is 'mathjax'? Will appreciate if you could give some help based on the question.

Comment: You can learn how to use MathJax [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/697421)...

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\E}{\mathrm{E}}$
$\newcommand{\Var}{\mathrm{Var}}$
$\newcommand{\Cov}{\mathrm{Cov}}$
There might be other ways also, but I am just giving an outline of how I did it in my Linear Models class (similar to that mentioned in [Applied Linear Statistical Models](http://users.stat.ufl.edu/%7Ewinner/sta4211/ALSM_5Ed_Kutner.pdf) by Kutner).

I have assumed my model to be of the form:
$$Y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1\cdot X_i+\epsilon_i$$ with the $\beta_1=\E\left[\beta_1^*\right]$ and $\beta_0=\E\left[\beta_0^*\right]$.

Thus, my estimated value of $Y$ at $x^*$ is
$$\hat{Y}^*=\beta_0^*+\beta_1^*\cdot x^*$$

Note that with some manipulations, you can write
$$\beta_1^*=\beta_1+\sum_{i=1}^n{\frac{X_i-\bar{X}}{\sum_{i=1}^n\left(X_i-\bar{X}\right)^2}\epsilon_i}$$

Find $\Var\left(\beta_1^*\right)$ from the above expression. Now you can use the alternate form of the regression which is
$$\frac{\hat{Y}^*-\bar{Y}}{x^*-\bar{x}}=\beta_1^*\\\implies\hat{Y}^*=\bar{Y}+\left(x^*-\bar{x}\right)\beta_1^*$$

Thus, we have,
$$\Var\left(\hat{Y}^*\right)=\Var\left(\bar{Y}\right)+\left(x^*-\bar{x}\right)^2\cdot\Var\left(\beta_1^*\right)+\left(x^*-\bar{x}\right)\Cov\left(\bar{Y},\beta_1^*\right)$$

What can be the value of $\Cov\left(\bar{Y},\beta_1^*\right)$?

> $$\Cov\left(\bar{Y},\beta_1^*\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{n}\frac{X_i-\bar{X}}{\sum_{i=1}^n\left(X_i-\bar{X}\right)^2}\Var\left(Y_i\right)\\=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\left(X_i-\bar{X}\right)}{\sum_{i=1}^n\left(X_i-\bar{X}\right)^2}$$
>  What is the value of this expression?

Finally, we get, from the above equation that
$$\Var\left(\hat{Y}^*\right)=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}+\left(x^*-\bar{x}\right)^2\cdot\frac{\sigma^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n\left(X_i-\bar{X}\right)^2}\\
=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}\left\{1+\frac{\left(x^*-\bar{x}\right)^2}{S_{xx}}\right\}$$

P.S.: There seems to be a typo in the question that you provided.